# gnu screen - get list of window titles

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

How can I obtain information (title, created time, visible content) about windows in a screen session? I need to do this in a script, so I am not looking for key bindings or interactive commands.

Something like tmux's `list-windows` would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2010-02/msg00031.html) in screen-users such a functionality has been implemented in screen.
Apparently I don't have a recent enough version for it to work but this should work in recent versions of screen. **[Edit]** I just tried with the latest git, it work even if it's not documented in `screen -h`

```
screen -Q windows
screen -Q select my_window
```

The first appearance of the `-Q` option was in [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/?id=8147d08647d59aba7accb748c42db2aba3f31bc4).

Comment: This seems to be the best way of going about it now. However, this has a few drawbacks in the implementation - 1. The display is limited to top few screens. 2. Invoking echo $(screen -Q windows) pauses the session as the screen's status bar is shown.

Comment: `screen -Q windows` outputs depend on screen width, so could be wrong if lot of windows or small width console. Have a look at [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1721586/178656)

Answer (score 3):

Try the sequence `Ctrl-a w` per the instructions [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE8QFjAA&url=http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935&ei=5EAyUKDMDI-70AG8lIG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHZ2-yTU4f3bZsgmuctObKysaag3w&cad=rja).

Personally, I use a .screenrc file that keeps this information on the bottom of the screen at all times (like a Windows task bar). My screen config (~/.screenrc) looks like:

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

Comment: Thank you, that is nice. But as I said in the question I am not looking for a key binding. I need to get the window name and other information from a bash script.

Comment: You're right, I misread your question. I'll do some research and post back if I find anything.

Answer (score 3):

In GNU Screen the default key binding to get a list of all the windows (and choose one to switch to) is:

```
C-a "
```

Answer (score 1):

### Finally I got it!

> #### I need to do this in a script...

#### Introduction

> I've openned 5 windows, closed window *`#2`* and opened a file with a problematic name *`4$ esp32.pdf`* in window *`#3`*...

```
screen -Q windows
0$ man screen  1*$ user@host$  3$ pdfread: 4$ esp32.pdf  4-$ root@server#
```

This string is near to unuseable! (See further, my *faster function*.)

#### My solution, as a function

Wanted to retrieve a correct list of open windows, even if some window title hold strings like `...2*$...` or so:

Here is a function searching for existing window number, from `0` to `99` (by default).

```bash
getWinList() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then
        local -n _outar="$2";shift 2
        else local _outar
    fi
    _outar=()
    local _string _pointer _maxid=${1:-99}
    case $_maxid in
        '' | *[!0-9]* )
            cat <<EOUsage
Usage:
    $FUNCNAME [-v <varname>] [INT]
       -v varname  Populate array "$varname" with window list
       [INT]       Optional last ID to check for existence (default 99)
EOUsage
            return 1
            ;;
    esac
    for ((_pointer=0;_pointer<=_maxid;_pointer++)); do
        _string=$(screen -p $_pointer -Q title) &&
            printf -v _outar[_pointer] %s "$_string"
    done
    printf >&2 '\e[A\n\e[K'
    [[ ${_outar[@]@A} != declare\ -a\ _outar=* ]] ||
        for _pointer in ${!_outar[@]};do
            printf '  %6s: %s\n' "[$_pointer]" "${_outar[_pointer]}"
        done
}
```

You could use `-v` option to store result into an *array* variable and add optional number of window to test for:

> I've openned 5 windows, closed window #2 and opened a file with a problematic name in window 3...

```
getWinList
     [0]: man screen
     [1]: user@host$
     [3]: pdfread: Little 4$ esp32.pdf
     [4]: root@server#

getWinList 3
     [0]: man screen
     [1]: user@host$
     [3]: pdfread: 4$ esp32.pdf


getWinList -v array 10                                          
declare  -p array
declare -a array=([0]="man screen" [1]="user@host\$" [3]="pdfread: 4\$ esp32.pdf" [4]="root@server#")
```

### Quicker but less reliable:

As it is

- based on output of `screen -Q windows` it is limited by current *window* width,
- based on *regular expression*, any window title matching this *re* could break then resulting array.

```bash
getWinListFast() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]]; then
        local -n _outar="$2";shift 2
        else local _outar
    fi
    _outar=()
    if [[ $1 ]]; then
            cat <<EOUsage
Usage:
    $FUNCNAME [-v <varname>]
       -v varname  Populate array "$varname" with window list
EOUsage
            return 1
    fi
    . <(screen -Q windows |
            sed '
                :a;
  s/^\(.*\n\|\)\([0-9]\+\)[*!-]*$ \(\([^ ]\| [^ ]\)\+\)\(  \(.*\)\|\) *$/\1[\2]="\3"\n\6/;
                ta;
                s/[|$]/\\&/g;
                s/.*/_outar=(&)\n/')
        printf >&2 '\e[A\n\e[K'
    [[ ${_outar[@]@A} != declare\ -a\ _outar=* ]] ||
        for _pointer in ${!_outar[@]};do
            printf '  %6s: %s\n' "[$_pointer]" "${_outar[_pointer]}"
        done
}
```